# PyCharm: all the commands for debugging are grayed out

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I opened a python script in PyCharm to debug it. I can run the program in the debugger (Run -> Debug...) but I can't set any breakpoints or do steps. All those commands are grayed out in the Run menu. Any idea what could be the problem and how to fix it?

[image: screenshot of the Run menu, as I see it]

Answer (score 0):

It took me way too long to figure this out, but it turns out that all debugging options are grayed out in the menu **if your cursor is on an empty line or a line that is a comment**. Try putting your cursor on an actual line with code. The "Toggle Line Breakpoint" option in the "Run" menu should now become active. After starting the script with "Run -> Debug", the breakpoint will be triggered (assuming the code reaches it) and the other debug options such as "Step over" become available.