# Why I can't able to do step in, step out in pycharm?

Tags: python, azure, pycharm

I am not able to click(I can say it's diabled) step in, step out, step over option in pycharm debugger

Comment: The only logical answer I found is that you're just executing script instead of running it in debug mode. Are breakpoints working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what is causing your issues but here is one possibility:

> All debugging options are grayed out in the menu **if your cursor is on an empty line or a line that is a comment**. Try putting your cursor on an actual line with code. The "Toggle Line Breakpoint" option in the "Run" menu should now become active. After starting the script with "Run -> Debug", the breakpoint will be triggered (assuming the code reaches it) and the other debug options such as "Step over" become available.

As mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665161/2891209

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to debug it is possible for step-in to **not show** you code which isn't pure python. Pycharm will do the best it can of course, but if the function you're trying to debug isn't native python be prepared for anything...

If you're trying to step into a python wrapped C library function

- Sometimes the debugger will  skip over that code completely.
- Sometimes you can walk the frames but the editor can't show you lines of code.
- Sometimes you'll be able to step into an empty skeleton of a function.

It really depends on how the library was created.